# paragraph symbol in word changed to a rectangle shape

Tags: symbols

in part of my document (specially in right to left language writing), the paragraph symbol has been changed to a rectangle shape. Considering that I am used to keeping the paragraph mark on while typing, this is a bit annoying. Is there a way to restore the previous icon?

Answer (score 0):

An empty rectangle in Word and many other text displaying programs usually means that the selected typeface does not contain information to the specific character. You can confirm this by temporarily changing typeface to a known working typeface. It may be necessary to perform an in-body change (and back again) if this is a critical issue for you.